# Connecting to SnowSQL Client using Snowflake Credentials

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have successfully installed SnowSQL Client version 1.2.5 and while trying to get log into my snowflake account, using account id, username and password, I am somehow unable to connect and get following error:
[snowsql unable to log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsvQH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be networking issue.  Have you tried to set that debug logging as directed?

To assist in situations like this, Snowflake has a tool which could help you determine if your client host is able to access all required network endpoints for your Snowflake account, it's called SnowCD, the documents are here and the installation is fairly straightforward:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

I'd recommend trying SnowCD as your first step, the next step would be to review any required proxy settings your organization might have.  I'd also double-check your "account name" argument, the URL looks OK to me but there is a nice writeup on the account name construction at this link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/connecting.html#your-snowflake-account-name

I hope this helps...Rich

Answer (score 0):

THANKS Rich for doing some R&D and sharing proposals. I got successfully logged into snowsql by providing my account id till ".aws". Hope it will help others struggling so far, like myself:
[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkrUX.png)

[demo log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6LR4.png)